# numbering in column and the other column get data from database

Tags: html

I wish to do something like this:

1. apple
2. bag
3. cat
4. dog

the first column: generate auto number start with 1.

the second column: get data from database

```
 <table>
    <?php do { ?>
<tr>
    <td><ol>
    <li></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["object"]; ?></td>
    </li></ol>
 </tr>

<?php } while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordset)); ?>
</table>
```

The coding above make like:

1 apple

1 bag

1 cat

1 dog

I do not know where am I wrong. Please correct me. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you're mixing `ol` and `table` elements together? Also your HTML is invalid, since you're opening a `td`, then an `ol` and `li`, then closing the `td` (leaving the `ol` and `li` open).

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new ordered list with each record. You're also mixing your ordered list in tables, which doesn't make sense - do one or the other.

Maybe something like:

```
<ol>
    <?php do { ?>
        <li><?php echo $row["object"]; ?></li>
    <?php } while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordset)); ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is near to what I want. 
i made it align center, but the things appeared: the numbering not in straight format, it follow the length of the data (second column)

Comment: @Chan: please could you reproduce these problems with a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Use the (relevant) HTML produced by your PHP script (since this is, basically, a [tag:html]/[tag:css] question it shouldn't matter that it's not dynamically-generated in the demo